# using sed to omit specific lines of a dataset

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have a dataset with  data separated by commas, here is an example:

```
id, date of birth, grade, explusion, serious misdemeanor, info
123,2005-01-01,5.36,1,1, 
582,1999-05-12,8.51,0,1
9274,2001-25-12,9.65,0,0,pass
21,2006-14-05,0.53,4,1,repeat
```

The case, is that I need to implement a regular expression using sed to remove all those records from the student dataset that do not have any explusion nor a serious misdemeanor. So the result of executing the command would be the third register of the previous sample.

```
sed -i "/^*,*,*,0,0$/d" file.csv
```

Any idea of what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `awk` to check Fields 4 and 5, and only return line where they are not `0`:

```sh
awk -F, '$4 != 0 ||  $5 != 0' file.csv > output.csv
```

Or, to get the other lines:

```sh
awk -F, '$4 == 0 &&  $5 == 0' file.csv > output.csv
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/NLSson).

You can also use

```sh
sed -i '/,0,0$/d' file.csv
```

With this, you will remove all lines ending with `,0,0`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/J1p0qI):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='id, date of birth, grade, explusion, serious misdemeanor
123,2005-01-01,5.36,1,1
582,1999-05-12,8.51,0,1
9274,2001-25-12,9.65,0,0
21,2006-14-05,0.53,4,1'
sed '/,0,0$/d' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
id, date of birth, grade, explusion, serious misdemeanor
123,2005-01-01,5.36,1,1
582,1999-05-12,8.51,0,1
21,2006-14-05,0.53,4,1
```

To see the other lines, use a reverse command like

```sh
sed  -i -n '/,0,0$/p' file.csv
```

It will print the lines that end with `,0,0`.

Comment: Hi Wiktor! I have tried the code you have proposed and it doesn't work either, I have also tried other combinations and I get nothing

Comment: @fortnite What is your exact expected output? If you need those where Field 4 and 5 are zero, use `awk -F, '$4 == 0 &&  $5 == 0' file.csv > output.csv`. Else, try `awk -F, '$4 != 0 ||  $5 != 0' file.csv > output.csv`

Comment: Well I don't get any error. After executing I don't get any results. And the problem is that I can't use awk, just sed for this..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think `*` means "anything" but it means "repeat the previous regular expression zero or more times, as many as possible". Regular expressions are different from wildcards as used in many shells and search engines, where `*` often does mean "any string".

The regular expression `.*` means "any character at all, repeated as many times as possible" but in this case you clearly mean `[^,]*` which means "any character which isn't a comma, repeated as many times as possible."

However, `sed` will happily match on a substring, so just

```
sed -i '/,0,0$/d' file.csv
```

should work, or equivalently

```
grep -v ',0,0$' file.csv >temp && mv temp file.csv
```

Comment: I have tried the code and I can't get it to work. Anyway I have edited the post a bit, and I have added a variable to the sample. However, after trying possible combinations it doesn't seem to work... Any idea?

Comment: If there's an optional sixth field I would go with Wiktor's Awk solution. But it's not really acceptable to change the question after you have received answers. Probably roll back your edit and accept Wiktor's answer, then ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements if you can't figure it out.